# TFS cross platform CLI tfx-cli offline installation

Tags: node.js, tfs

I want to install tfx-cli on a machine which does not have access to Internet.

I have installed nodejs with node-v6.4.0-x64.msi.

Per msdn guide after installing node.js install tfx-cli with below command

`npm install -g tfx-cli`

But the above requires internet connection.

How to install tfx-cli in a machine which has no internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using nodejs-v6.4.0.  Afraid there is no way to install without internet access.

Certainly, there are some ways to use npm  for offline pack installation. Such as [offline-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-npm)  However it's not suitable for your case:

> npm >= v3.x bundled with node >= v5 has broken this project.
>   preinstall script is since then called after requests to npm registry
>   are made. This makes it impossible for offline-npm to start as a
>   registry server.

And [Use local-npm for offline NPM package installation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xinjinms/2016/08/25/use-local-npm-for-offline-npm-package-installation/), however you still should install many other things from internet. It doesn't make sense. If you have internet, you could directly install it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me try with a previous version of node.js where offline-npm works. May be that could help I suppose.